# Converting incidence of new diagnoses to DALYs, or vice-versa

Tags: epidemiology

A [recent Nature Medicine study](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-023-02521-2) looked at new diagnoses of a wide range conditions from electronic health records, for both a group with a particular exposure (here, Covid infection) and an unexposed control group, across four six-month periods since the exposure (0-6 months, 6-12 months etc).

In the actual study paper and study data files, the authors don't provide the raw numbers/incidence for these diagnoses. Instead, for each condition (and broken out for each 6-month block), they provide "DALYs per 30 days" (per 1000 people).
As far as I can see they don't explain how they went from the incidence/new diagnoses figures in the health records they looked at, to the DALYs per 30 days they give in the study, other than that they used a "health burden coefficient" for each condition that's given in Table S16 in the supplementary data.

Does anyone know how they would/should (assuming these are the same thing) have done this conversion? And, conversely, what the right way is to convert their DALYs per capita per 30 days (within each six month period) back to incidence of new diagnoses for those conditions for the entirety (i.e., not per 30 days) of each six month period? Thanks in advance for any help.